# On proving Minkowski space is a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds, physics

Since the Minkowski space is just $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a different inner product does that mean it's a manifold ? And if it is are there any easy proofs or a hint, so I can work it myself?

Comment: yes it's still a manifold. recall that smooth manifolds by themselves do not care about the geometric structure of inner products/Riemannian metrics/Lorentzian metrics. Smooth manifolds are only about the underlying set and the maximal atlas. In your case R4 is the set and there is the usual maximal atlas (the one which includes the identity chart), and with this it trivially becomes a smooth manifold. In other other words, forget about the extra geometric information of the (pseudo) inner product and prove it is a manifold in the usual way.

Comment: It's always a good idea to try it yourself first (using the basic definition of a manifold) and post a question if you get stuck or aren't sure about some of the steps.

Comment: @Deane can you provide me the definition you think its good to prove it, because i read that stuff for myself i dont have a course on manifolds and on the internet and the books i have there are many definitions of the manifold.

Comment: Pick the one you found easiest to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an attempt and most likely it's not correct because I am confused about this things in general.
That been said, let $M $ to be the Minkowski space and take $x \in M$, $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{R}^4$
and consider the Identity function $\psi :M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$, $\psi(x)=x$

$\psi $ is an homeomorphism

the Jacobian matrix has rank 4
and $\psi^{-1}(0)=M \cap \mathbb{R}^4$
therefore, $M$ is an 4-d manifold

Did I have any luck with that? Can someone help me and correct me?

Comment: Yes, any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, including all of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is a manifold by defining the identity map as a coordinate chart. That can be extended to a maximal atlas. The more important fact is that the Minkowski inner product is a smooth function on $\mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to this manifold topology.

Comment: Can we also say that every field $\mathbb{F}$ with  inner product is a manifold? Also thank you for answering.

Comment: If you can define a bijective map from the field to an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, yes. But the map and the manifold structure will have no relationship with the field structure at all, so the manifold structure is useless for studying the field itself. Remember that we use coordinate charts to define the topology and smooth structure of the manifold via the properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So $\mathbb{R}^n$ it self is trivially a manifold using its own existing topological properties, which in turn are defined by the vector space structure.